# Determine whether a source resolution belongs to the specified aspect ratio

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, aspect-ratio, imaging

I would like to determine whether a source resolution belongs to the specified aspect ratio, in C# or VB.NET.

Currently I wrote this:

```
/// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <summary>
/// Determine whether the source resolution belongs to the specified aspect ratio.
/// </summary>
/// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <param name="resolution">
/// The source resolution.
/// </param>
/// 
/// <param name="aspectRatio">
/// The aspect ratio.
/// </param>
/// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <returns>
/// <see langword="true"/> if the source resolution belongs to the specified aspect ratio; 
/// otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.
/// </returns>
/// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static bool ResolutionIsOfAspectRatio(Size resolution, Point aspectRatio) {

    return (resolution.Width % aspectRatio.X == 0) && 
           (resolution.Height % aspectRatio.Y == 0);

}
```

VB.NET:

```
Public Shared Function ResolutionIsOfAspectRatio(resolution As Size, 
                                                 aspectRatio As Point) As Boolean

    Return ((resolution.Width Mod aspectRatio.X) AndAlso 
            (resolution.Height Mod aspectRatio.Y)) = 0

End Function
```

Example usage:

```
Size resolution = new Size(1920, 1080);
Point aspectRatio = new Point(16, 9);

bool result = ResolutionIsOfAspectRatio(resolution, aspectRatio);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I just want to ensure that I'm not missing anything of the aspect ratio concept, that maybe could cause unexpected results when using the function I wrote.

Then, my question is: is that algorithm ok for all the cases?, if not, what modifications I should do to perform this operation properly?.

EDIT: I noticed that algorithm its totally wrong, it takes 640x480 as 16:9 aspect ratio. I didn't read enough about the basics how to calculate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a error in your calculation. Just mod each value separately doesn't validate the aspect ratio.

e.g.

```
Size res = new Size(1920, 1080);
Point aspect = new Point(16, 9);  //1080%9==0 valid and true
bool result = (res.Width % aspect.X == 0) &&(res.Height % aspect.Y == 0);
```

is true but

```
Point aspect = new Point(16, 10); //1080%10==0 invalid and true!
```

is also true.

The correct way to calculate is

```
bool result = res.Width / aspect.X == res.Height / aspect.Y; //1920/16 == 1080/9
```

Comment: I know it is frowned upon to thank someone here in the comments box, but I thank you.

Comment: I just read an article here that that may be changing. We may be allowed to be human beings (briefly) to say please and thank you.